# Saved table not showing up in Object Exploer in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, ssms

I created new tables `Faculty` and `Specialty` as described in the link below, but I do not see them under databases in the Object Explorer. Also, if I click on 'edit', I do not see 'Intellisense' anywhere. What is going on?

http://www.cs.trinity.edu/~thicks/Tutorials/MSSQL-Server-Management-Studio-DB-Construction/MSSQL-Server-Management-Studio-DB-Construction.html

Comment: tried Refreshing your explorer?

Comment: how do I do that? I am new to using Management Studio

Comment: on database folder in object explorer right click and refresh

Comment: mark as answer below if it was helpful,i have posted the pic

Comment: I now have a new problem. When I right-click on it, I do not see 'Open Table' anywhere. If click on `edit top 200 rows`, I am unable to add new entries to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Refreshing the database in object explorer.

[image]

Comment: I now have a new problem. When I right-click on it, I do not see 'Open Table' anywhere. If click on `edit top 200 rows`, I am unable to add new entries to the table

Comment: what error pops when try to edit / write ? or try insert using queries

Comment: There's no error pop. It says at the bottom 'cell is read only'

Comment: try SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF

Comment: Try the USE statement on the database again too perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go your database and write this query:

```
USE DBName --Change the database name in which you have created your table
GO 
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
             AND  TABLE_NAME = 'Faculty'))
BEGIN
print 'table exists'    
END
```

Check if your table exists in the database. If the table is created then it will be listed here else there might be some problem while creation.

And if the above query shows the table which you are looking for in the database then I would recommend to restart your management studio and check again.

Comment: Apparently so, they show up in the Results in the tab below

Comment: @user4352158:- You can use `the Insert into` command to insert new rows into the table.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the view that management studio uses to display table information.

1. Create your table
2. If you don't see the new table in mgt studio
3. select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
4. You should see the new table

Not sure why this happened, server might need more memory / cpu..